# how to get the set of the two ends of the relation in set theory

Tags: event-b

Here, I have a relation `r ∈ A ↔ B`, and if I only know about `r`, how can I get the set `A` and `B`? Is it possible？

Actually, I doubt whether it can be done according to what I know, and if it's impossible ,I need to find some new methods to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actually used elements in `r`, use domain and range: `dom(r)` and `ran(r)`. If you want all possible values, just use `A` resp. `B`.